# With SBT how do I sequence tasks from plugin before running a test

Tags: sbt, flyway

How can I run sequential tasks that come from a plugin such as flyway before running a test, for example if I wanted to run:
`flywayClean` then `flywayMigrate` then `integrationTests`, how would I do that?

The problem is that sbt doesn't really support anything with side-effects like a db.

I looked at examples of sequencing tasks here:
http://eed3si9n.com/sequencing-tasks-with-sbt-sequential

I've tried working through these, and I can follow the basic example, but I can't figure out how to run a task from a plugin such as `flyway`.

It seems like part of the problem is that `flywayClean` and `flywayMigrate` are both of type `TaskKey[Unit]`, where the sbt-sequential examples are using `Def.Setting[Task[Unit]]`.

sbt has so much complexity that I can't quite figure out how to resolve the `Task` associated with a given `TaskKey` and then transform that into a `Setting[Task[Unit]]`.

Answer (score 3):

I setup my sbt build to do a `flywayClean`, then a `flywayMigrate` before running the tests:

```
executeTests in Test := {
  (executeTests in Test).dependsOn(flywayMigrate.dependsOn(flywayClean)).value
}
```

Comment: Hi James, how do you run flyway task specifically for Test settings. In my build I have flyway variables for my test env: 
flywayUrl in Test := "jdbc:h2:/tmp/flyway:4200/"
I would like to run flyway for my test environment settings and not main ones let me know if you have a clue please

Comment: If you want to run flyway with the configured test flyway environment, you should juste edit James' answer for .....   (executeTests in Test).dependsOn((flywayMigrate in Test).dependsOn(flywayClean in Test)).value

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can have a task that executes a lot of other tasks sequentially. Is this what you want to do? If the tasks are from a plugin you need to bring it into scope. If it's from an auto-plugin then pretty much all its task should be in scope without you explicitly importing them.

```
lazy val mtaskA = taskKey[Unit]("a")

lazy val mtaskB = taskKey[String]("b")

lazy val mtaskC = taskKey[Int]("c")

mtaskA := {
    println("hello")
}

mtaskB := {
    "hello-2"
}

mtaskC := {
    2
}


lazy val cmp = taskKey[Unit]("cmp")

cmp := {
    mtaskA.value
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println( mtaskB.value )
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println( mtaskC.value )
}
```